# Elecrtrolytic Capacitors (Soldering)

Tags: capacitor

I have a question. Changing a capacitor. But the physical body of the new capacitor is bigger and longer. Can i solder it with its terminals intact so i can bend them and fit the new capacitor inside the enclosure? With terminals 3-Centimeters long, will it cause any trouble (Interference)? Thanks

Comment: It is 25 Volts 680uF Capacitor Router Motherboard

Comment: It will probably be okay. Be careful of short circuits

Comment: Thanks. Yes I took care of the terminals not to touch each other and other components

Comment: I like to use a little RTV silicone adhesive to help hold these "flying" capacitors in place.  Because if it is ever subject to vibration, the legs could weaken and break.

Comment: If you do use silicone to hold the cap in place, make sure to get the 'neutral cure' type. "Normal" silicone release acetic acid as it cures and that's not healthy for electronics.

Comment: rdtsc and brhans thank you for your kind suggestions. I used hot gun silicon. Is it ok?